# Background image does not properly adjust to screen size

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to make a responsive site using skel.js and skel-panels.js. Basically what these libraries do is allow you to make breakpoints for the screen size and allow you to put content in hidden panels when the screen size changes.

I have an image covering the background of a container div. The problem I am having is that when I try to change the size of the screen, the background image does not "include" the new element that is inserted via skel-panels.js, therefore becoming smaller than I want it to be.

My markup:

```
    <div id="intro">
    <!-- Nav -->
        <div>
            <nav id="nav">
                <a href="#">Home</a>
                <a href="#">About</a>
                <a href="#">Blog</a>
                <a href="#" class="skel-panels-include" data-action="togglePanel" data-args="bottomPanel">Contact</a>
            </nav>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
        <!-- Header -->


            <div id="header">
                <h1 id="title">Title</h1>
                <img id="logo" src="images/logo.png">
            </div>
            <div>
                <section id="hero"> 
                    <h2>Title</h2>
                    <p>Catchphrase!</p>
                    <a href="#" class="button">Join the Fight</a>
                </section>  
            </div>
        </div>
     </div>
```

My CSS:

```
#intro {
background:url(../images/bg.png) top center no-repeat fixed;
position: relative;
background-size: cover;
text-align: center;
color: #fff;
}
```

This is what this looks like:

Fullwidth - [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/B6hXo.jpg

Narrow View -  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uV7MV.jpg

It looks like the markup gets messed up when a new div is inserted (nav button in the narrow view). Any insights would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I should note that the logo has a 5em margin on top. This is why there is a space between the top of the background image/logo and the top of the page. `#logo {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  margin: 5em auto;
  width: auto;
  vertical-align: middle;
 }`

Answer (score 0):

try

```
#intro { 
  background: url(../images/bg.png) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: No, didn't work. It still has the same problem. Thanks anyway tho.